# Elasticsearch query search by words and then order by date for each index properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I need one query that will give me results like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Has word/words in keywords -> xx.xx.2018 (newest date)
. . . 
Has word/words in keywords -> xx.xx.1900 (oldest date)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Has word/words in description -> xx.xx.2018 (newest date)
... 
Has word/words in description -> xx.xx.1900 (oldest date)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Has word/words in title -> xx.xx.2018 (newest date)
... 
Has word/words in title -> xx.xx.1900 (oldest date)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried simple sort by date with query boost on specific index (keywords, description, title). Couldn't make it stick. Because hits are ordered by date and then by queries.

I've found [multi search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) but I can not use it.

The closest I've got is:

```
"query": {
    "function_score":{
        "functions": [
            {
                "gauss": {
                    "date_taken": {
                        "origin": 'now',
                        "scale": '182d',
                        "offset": '366d',
                        "decay": 0.9
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "date_taken" ,   
                "factor": 1.2,
                "modifier": "sqrt",
                }
            }
        ],
        "query": {
            "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
                { "match": { "keywords": {"query": text, "boost": 9999999999999999999999999} }},
                { "match": { "description":  {"query": text, "boost": 999} }},
                { "match": { "title":  text }},
                ],
                "tie_breaker": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using decay on the date, to basically get order by date, and then using boost on the queries. Giving hits better `_score`.

```
"sort": [
    {
        "_score" : {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
]
```

Problem I am facing is that in some cases, when I have small amount of hits (50-100), ordering is fine. In others I am loosing ordering by date or I am losing order by the word/words hits. For example hit without `keywords` is in front of others.

Also I have the problem with repeating words. Example:

```
"keywords": "TEST, something else, TEST"
```

Found [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-options.html) options `docs` haven't tried it yet.

I am using elasticsearch 2.3

Part of the index :

```
"mappings": {
   "image": {
     "properties": {
       "keywords": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "simple",
         "boost": 12
       },
       "title": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "simple",
         "boost": 11
       },
       "description": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "simple",
         "boost": 10
       },
       "date_taken": {
         "type": "date",
         "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
       },
```

Is this even possible? Do you have any suggestion/example you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't make the `decay` work as needed, and there was no other solutions.
I made a proxy server. That is rewriting the request between my app and the elastic.